# Computation of magnitude of the secondary

Tags: binary-star, apparent-magnitude

How to approximately compute the magnitude of the secondary in a binary when I know the magnitude of the primary, masses, radii, and approximate luminosities for both of them, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: What particular problem did you encounter? What is your own research on these two(!) questions? How did the readily available sources  not help you?

Comment: I do not have the magnitude of the secondary - that is the problem. What are the available sources, I have not found anything that is clear for me.

Comment: Are you aware of the *definition* of luminosity and magnitude? What did you search for? What ressources did you check? Why did they not help? With all respect, but your real issue seems to be the google-foo here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the trick here will be to use the magnitude of the primary ($m_1$) and the luminosities of the two ($L_1$ and $L_2$) to get to $m_2$. When first googling for the relationship between luminosity and magnitude you could easily get confused because apparent magnitude isn't a measurement of luminosity, its a measurement of flux! The difference between two magnitudes is related to the ratio of the two fluxs like this:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
m_1-m_2=-2.5\log\frac{f_1}{f_2}
\end{equation}
This is done because the definition of the magnitude scale was so that a difference of 5 magnitudes is equivilent to a flux ratio of 100:1 (try the math out to test this!).

But, you don't have fluxs, you have luminosities! Since your stars are in a binary we can use a little trick. To go from flux to luminosity you use the following relationship:
$$f = \frac{L}{4\pi d^2}$$
where $d$ is the distance to the object in question. Substituting this into the first equation we get
$$m_1-m_2=-2.5\log\frac{L_1/(4\pi d_1^2)}{L_2/(4\pi d_2^2)} = -2.5\log(\frac{L_1}{L_2}\frac{d_2^2}{d_1^2})$$
Since you are looking at a binary $d_1=d_2$! So this simplifies down to the relation you want, $m_2$ as a function of $m_1$, $L_1$, and $L_2$
$$\boxed{m_2=m_1+2.5\log\frac{L_1}{L_2}}$$
Hopefully this helps! the magnitude system is the bane of my existence so I have to look this up about once a week even though I'm getting a PhD in astronomy D:

Comment: Thank you so much